# Xcode Expected Expression

Tags: objective-c

I keep getting the error 'Expected Expression regarding the if (Start) == YES) line and I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
#import "SimpleTableViewController.h"

@interface SimpleTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SimpleTableViewController

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

if (Start) == YES)  {

    Intro1.hidden = YES;
    Intro2.hidden = YES;
    Intro3.hidden = YES;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BirdMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]

    Start = NO;
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
Start = YES;

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Remove the closing bracket after Start. For every closing bracket there must be an opening bracket - and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (Start) == YES)
```

in above line you have 1 starting bracket and 2 closing bracket.
**Solution** add 1 more starting bracket or delete 1 closing bracket.

```
 if ((Start) == YES)
 or

if (Start == YES)
```

Comment: Compare bool variables with `YES` is wrong. BOOL can store also numbers 2, 3, 4, ... And this values will be equal `TRUE`, but condition `Start == YES` will give `FALSE`. So condition should be just `if (Start)` or `if (Start != NO)`

Comment: @Cy-4AH i dunno what is the type of Start. giving him the the solution of his error.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Start)
{
    Intro1.hidden = YES;
    Intro2.hidden = YES;
    Intro3.hidden = YES;

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(BirdMove) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]

    Start = NO;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to improve your answer.

Comment: @Till, I think all is obvious. You can edit my answer if you want add somethig.

Comment: Thank you! and Ill be sure to include more information in my question next time I rarely use the site and am not quite accustomed to the unspoken rules. Thanks again for the quick response